# Find data from first file when matched and print in next line after matched line in file2

Tags: python

I have `file1` as

```
1 AN3D3BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(Y1),.A2(),.A3(),.Z(v1)); |2
2 BUFFSKFD32BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(v1),.Z(v2)); |3
3 GND2D1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v2),.A2(),.ZN(v3)); |5
4 CKBD6BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(v3),.Z(v4)); |6
5 BUFFSKRD32BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(v4),.Z(v5)); |7
6 OIAI21D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v5),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(v6)); |10
7 AOI33D1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v6),.A2(),.A3(),.B1(),.B2(),.B3(),.ZN(v7)); |14
8 ND2D4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v7),.A2(),.ZN(v8)); |16
```

And `file2` as

```
9 AO21D4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(Y2),.A2(),.B(),.Z(v9)); |2
10 AOI221D4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v9),.A2(),.B1(),.B2(),.C(),.ZN(v10)); |6
11 AOI21OPTPAD4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v10),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(v11)); |9
12 AN3D6BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v11),.A2(),.A3(),.Z(v12)); |11
13 IND4D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v12),.B1(),.B2(),.B3(),.ZN(v13)); |16
```

I want to `compare last digit i.e digit after | in both the files` and if they match,  i want to get last bracket data of that match line from file1 and copy it to `()` in next line after match line in file2 and write in file2.

> In above input files, `line1 from file1 matches with line 9 of file2` so i want to copy last bracket data i.e `(v1) from file1` and replace the `()` in next line after match line in file2 i.e `as line 9 was matched in file2 then replace its next line i.e line 10 () with last line bracket data of file1 and append in file2`.

I tried the below code, it works fine but the replace () is happening in same matched line of file2 not in next line of matched line on file2

```
with open('file1','r') as fin:
   for line in fin:
       l=line[-5:]
       l2=re.sub('^.*\((.*?)\)[^\(]*$','\g<1>',line)   ### to find the value of last bracket 

fout=open('file2','r')
fout1=open('file2','a')

for line2 in fout:                                                    
   if "()" in line2:                                                           
      k=line2[-5:]                                                        
      if l==k:                                                                    
          k=line2.replace("()","("+l2+")",1)                                                               
          print >> fout1,k+'\n'
```

I want output as below

```
9 AO21D4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(Y2),.A2(),.B(),.Z(v9)); |2
10 AOI221D4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v9),.A2(),.B1(),.B2(),.C(),.ZN(v10)); |6
11 AOI21OPTPAD4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v10),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(v11)); |9
12 AN3D6BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v11),.A2(),.A3(),.Z(v12)); |11
13 IND4D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v12),.B1(),.B2(),.B3(),.ZN(v13)); |16

10 AOI221D4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v9),.A2(v1),.B1(),.B2(),.C(),.ZN(v10)); |6
11 AOI21OPTPAD4BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(v10),.A2(v4),.B(),.ZN(v11)); |9
```

Comment: I don't think you should be opening the same file for both reading & appending at the same time. Better to create a temporary file with your edits, then once you are finished, delete the original file2 and replace it. I know this doesn't necessarily answer your question, but it maybe the cause of your problem.

Comment: I understand your point. But The code worked fine, only problem is ```i want to move to next line in file2 when match is found and replace data  in the next line after match line.``` in code ```if l==k:                                                                    
          k=line2.replace("()","("+l2+")",1)``` i am replacing in same matched line as i dont know how can I move to next line after match is found in file2 .

Comment: The code doesn't work fine, though. It appends to the end of the file. Part of the reason for this is because you're trying to read & write the file at the same time. This is not a good idea and is causing your problem.

Comment: Ok@Joe Todd. I will write it in different file. but  How can I approch then to replace data in the next line after the match line not in match line as I am doing in above code ```if l==k: k=line2.replace("()","("+l2+")",1)```. ```k``` is pointing to matched line in file2. But I want next line after this matched line and do replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses a list of strings to get around the temporary file issue. This will work fine so long as the number of replacement lines doesn't get too huge to hold in memory.

It also assumes that you wouldn't have a case where two adjacent lines from file2 match with the same line of file1, because the `next(fout)` means that this next line won't be checked against file1.

```
import re

new_lines = []
with open('file1','r') as fin:
   for line in fin:
      l=line[-5:]
      l2=re.sub('^.*\((.*?)\)[^\(]*$','\g<1>',line)   ### to find the value of last bracket

      fout=open('file2','r')

      # Store altered lines in a list of strings
      for line2 in fout:
         k=line2[-5:]
         if "()" in line2 and l==k:
            try:
               nextline = next(fout)
               k=nextline.replace("()","("+l2+")",1)
               new_lines.append(k)
            except StopIteration: # Don't care if we reach end of file2
               pass

fout.close()

# Now write list of strings to file
with open('file2', 'a') as fout:
   fout.write("\n")
   for line in new_lines:
      fout.write(line)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.. one more doubt, Since here i am appending in same file, What if i want to write complete data of file2 after replacing different file.?

Comment: If I understand your question, you can just use shutil.copy to copy file2 to another file. Could you mark the answer as accepted? Thanks